# How to use moveTo and locateOnScreen with duration and tween features on PyAutoGUI?

Tags: python, bots, pyautogui

I was using the `moveTo` function with coordinates, but I notice that sometimes the coordinates are changed, so getting those coordinates manually every time is not being that practical as I wanted.

So I'm trying to use the `moveTo` function with `locateOnScreen`, the problem is: if I add the **tween** and **duration** feature I got an error.

I was using:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(1677, 610, confidence=0.8), np.random.uniform(0.8,2), pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
```

Then I changed to:

```
Img = 'test.png'

pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(Img, confidence=0.8), np.random.uniform(0.8,2), pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
```

But with the function above I'm getting the error: `When passing a sequence for firstArg, secondArg must not be passed and default to None (received 1.4511874585715279)`.

The function only works if I do this:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(Img))
```

But if I use this way, the mouse cursor will instantly move to the new coordinates which I don't want. I would expect more like a "human" behavior.

How to use `moveTo` and `locateOnScreen` with duration and tween features on PyAutoGUI?

Comment: The tween duration is the *third* parameter to `.moveTo()`, not the second.  Insert a `None` as the second parameter to fix this.

Comment: @jasonharper I'm sorry, I just noticed that my questions wasn't updated with the third parameter. I'm still getting error by this way.

Comment: The tweening function likewise has to be the fourth parameter, not the third.  My advice still stands.

Comment: That's true, it worked! Thank you. Do you want to answer and I accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the documentation from pyautogui [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html), I was using a different approach that was using `pyautogui.center` function:

```
button7point = pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('calc7key.png'))
```

Output:

```
button7point.x
1441
button7point.y
582
```

But as @jasonharper mentioned in the comments, I was able to find the image directly from the function `locateOnScreen` just by add `None` to the parameter, so the answer is:

```
Img = 'test.png'

pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(Img, confidence=0.8), None, np.random.uniform(0.8,2), pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
```